# BarLegend not showing full range when indicated inside a function

Tags: legending

I am trying to show a `BarLegend` for a `MatrixPlot`. I am aware that doing `MatrixPlot[ ... PlotLegends -> Automatic]` should work, but for some reason it isn't. The function I'm using to specify the colour coding is somewhere inside `myfunction`, and even when plotting it alone I can't get the full thing to show.

This code snippet reproduces the problem. I think that if I get this to work I may be able to have `MatrixPlot` working with the legend.

```
myfunction[range_] := Block[{bar, something},
  bar = (Blend[{{range[[1]], 
        Lighter@Cyan}, {range[[1]] - range[[3]]/2, 
        Orange}, {range[[2]], Darker@Red}}, #] &);
  BarLegend[{bar[#] &, {range[[1]], range[[2]]}}]
  ]
myfunction[{-3, 10, 13}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had initially intended to make this as a comment, but I think expanding on what is happening would be very useful. There are two issues here, and it is helpful to look at the `InputForm` of what `myfunction` produces:

```
InputForm@myfunction[{-3, 10, 13}]
(* BarLegend[{bar[#1] & , {-3, 10}}] *)
```

The first issue is that `BarLegend` does not evaluate; it, and the other legend functions, have no transformative `DownValues`. Their `DownValues` only check validity, but otherwise leave them unevaluated. They are then handled during markup, in much the same way that `Graphics` is.  Second, `bar` will not evaluate outside of the `Block`, unless it has `DownValues`/`UpValues` in the enclosing scope. Taken together, when `BarLegend` is marked up, there is no function for it to operate on.

The solution is to use either `Module` or `With`. Using `Module`, though,

```
mfModule[range_] := 
 Module[{bar, something}, 
  bar = (Blend[{{range[[1]], 
        Lighter@Cyan}, {range[[1]] - range[[3]]/2, 
        Orange}, {range[[2]], Darker@Red}}, #] &);
  BarLegend[{bar[#] &, {range[[1]], range[[2]]}}]]
```

results in an evaluation leak

```
InputForm@mfModule[{-3, 10, 13}]
(* BarLegend[{bar$3604[#1] & , {-3, 10}}] *)
```

as the internal variable, `bar$`, will not be released until all references to it are gone. So, I prefer using `With`,

```
mfWith[range_] := 
 With[{bar = (Blend[{{range[[1]], 
         Lighter@Cyan}, {range[[1]] - range[[3]]/2, 
         Orange}, {range[[2]], Darker@Red}}, #] &)},
  BarLegend[{bar[#] &, {range[[1]], range[[2]]}}]]
```

as it places the function directly into the result:

```
InputForm@mfWith[{-3, 10, 13}]
(* BarLegend[{(Blend[{{{-3, 10, 13}[[1]], Lighter[Cyan]}, 
  {{-3, 10, 13}[[1]] - {-3, 10, 13}[[3]]/2, Orange}, 
  {{-3, 10, 13}[[2]], Darker[Red]}}, #1] & )[#1] & , {-3, 10}}]*)
```

Comment: `BarLegend` does have down values, though mainly for argument checking purposes.

Comment: @BrettChampion yep, I see that now, and how they work. Will figure out how to rephrase ...